# Building OSRM on Ubuntu, CMake fails with "Intel TBB NOT found!" message

Tags: cmake, osrm

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-osrm-ubuntu-20-04-open-source-routing-machine) to build **OSRM-backend** from source.

When it says:

```
cd build
cmake /srv/osrm/osrm-backend/
```

I got this error message:

```
ERROR: Intel TBB NOT found!
-- Looked for Threading Building Blocks in /usr
CMake Error at cmake/FindTBB.cmake:274 (message):
  Could NOT find TBB library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:533 (find_package)
```

I have installed TBB:

```
sudo apt install -y libtbb
```

And it looks good:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so.2
(...)
```

But cmake fails.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find [the solution](https://bytemeta.vip/repo/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/6264), althought, it says, there're duplications:

> This is a duplicate of #6248 and #6253. Building with
> `cmake -DENABLE_MASON=ON` will fix it.

Surprisingly, on MacOS, there's a simple workaround:

```
brew install osrm-backend
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go to the [file](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/cmake/FindTBB.cmake#L274) from the error message and see that it can't find the library at some default paths.

It means we have to help `cmake` a bit. At the [beginning](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/cmake/FindTBB.cmake#L43) we can see that this module respects `TBB_INSTALL_DIR`. So I'd try setting it while configuring the project.

Comment: Tried, did not work, TBB is installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Anyway, it is needed when TBB is installed in `/opt/tdd` or similar.

Comment: You can just log what's inside `_TBB_LIBRARY_DIR` here https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/cmake/FindTBB.cmake#L213 That's where `cmake` looks for the library. And you can see this list contains `_TBB_INSTALL_DIR`. So you have to add correct value and it should work. Or just call `find_library()` yourself and try to make it work. It'll be the key to understanding.